# Will Google's App Engine security features suit me well?

Tags: google-app-engine, rest, https, security

I just got an Android phone, and of course I am itching to make an app for the platform.

I have an idea in mind, but it requires that I have a server that will offer REST-style services to the client phones. I have neither the skills on server security nor the money for a verified SSL certificate. I also wouldn't feel that great having people's login information (username, password) on my server, as I could get easily hacked.

So in a nutshell, will App Engine help out with these aspects? Basically, I do not trust myself in coding security-critical code, such as logins, and account creation/deletion. Maybe I'm making it seem more difficult than it really is, but I rather have that stuff taken care of already.

Comment: You just bought a smartphone, but you can't afford $10/yr for an SSL certificate?

Comment: @NickJohnson, read the rest of the question (2nd paragraph)? And a $10 SSL certificate is not going to be the same quality as Google's.

Comment: @gatoatigrado I read the whole question, and answered it appropriately below, but making useful points in the rest of the question doesn't make the initial point any less silly. And the "quality" of your SSL certificate is completely irrelevant as long as it verifies in users' browsers.

Comment: $10/yr SSL cert? Wow, I guess I haven't been looking around hard enough. I've yet to see prices that cheap. :P

Comment: yeah, I have one now. [ http://www.namecheap.com/ssl-certificates/comodo/positivessl-certificate.aspx ]. They seem to work fine. In follow up to what I said earlier, having an SSL is no guarantee your server is secure though, and won't protect you against spammers. A SSL certificate also won't implement things like account lock-out after a brute-force attack, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

App Engine supports integrating with Android apps for authentication, as described [here](http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2011/05/android-meet-app-engine-app-engine-meet.html). In that respect, it's an excellent choice for a backend for an Android app.

It's good to not have unwarranted faith in your ability to write secure apps - but bear in mind that no platform is a silver bullet, and there's always possible avenues for security vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Oauth in GAE works quite well, companies like Facebook and Dropbox and Twitter are using it. Access_token is send to the app (or browser) and with this access_token, the app can access the user's account without needed the username + password.

With GAE, you can use encryption (pycrypto) when storing the access_token on the user app, only to be decrypted by GAE when user logs in.